# Have two fields to identified users in symfony 7.0

Tags: php, symfony

I have these security.yaml where I want to established two fields from my db.

```
security:
    providers:
        usuarios:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Usuarios
                property: correo
    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\Usuarios:
            algorithm: plaintext
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: usuarios
            form_login:
                login_path: ctrl_login
                check_path: ctrl_login
                default_target_path: categorias
            logout:
                path:   ctrl_logout
                target: ctrl_login
```

I have look up symfony documentation and it doesnt give an exact answer if you want to establish two different fields to log in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your security requirements do not match any of the [provided standard methods](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#authenticating-users) (which they don't) you will need to create your own [custom authenticator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authenticator.html).

It's still recommended to read through the https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html docs to get an understanding of how it all fits together.